# Dudas al encriptar archivo HLS con ffmpeg

Tags: encriptación, openssl, hls

soy novata y tengo una pregunta. Estoy intentando convertir un video .mp4 a formato HLS usando ffmpeg. 
Lo pude hacer  con:

`ffmpeg -y -i pruebavideo.mp4 -hls_time 9 -hls_segment_filename "fileSequence%d.ts" -hls_playlist_type vod prog_index.m3u`8

Pero el problema es que necesito que esté encriptado con AES128 y no lo logro. Estoy siguiendo las indicaciones de este [blog](https://hlsbook.net/how-to-encrypt-hls-video-with-ffmpeg/#comment-161)

1- Instalé openssl y ejecuto el CMD desde la ubicación del archivo .mp4.

2 -Genero el key.file con:

```
openssl rand 16 > enc.key
```

Y se crea un archivo en la misma carpeta donde tengo el video.

3- Luego genero el IV con:

```
openssl rand -hex 16
```

4- Luego indica que tengo que crear un archivo *enc.keyinfo* para indicarle a Ffmpeg donde buscar la key con el siguiente formato:

> Key URI
>
> Ruta de ubicación al key file
>
> IV (optional)

5- Creo un archivo en el bloc de notas llamado *enc.keyinfo*. Pero no sé que poner en Key URI, ya que mis archivos van a estar alojados en Amazon S3, puedo alojar la key en mi web y poner esa dirección?

6 -Por otro lado, en la ruta de ubicación del archivo key.file indico la carpeta donde está guardado ese archivo:

> C:\Users\Dmar\Documents\Videos

7- Es decir que el archivo hls_key_info_file me queda así:

> https:/probandoprueba.com/keys/key.file
>
> C:\Users\Dmar\Documents\Videos
>
> ecd0d06eaf884d8226c33928e87efa33

8 -Pero cuando uso el siguiente código para convertir y encriptar mi video, me da error:

```
ffmpeg -y \
-i pruebavideo.mp4 \
-hls_time 9 \
-hls_key_info_file enc.keyinfo
-hls_playlist_type vod \
-hls_segment_filename "fileSequence%d.ts" \
prog_index.m3u8
```

Error:

> error opening key info file enc.keyinfo. Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory. Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- [aac @ 0000000002f900c0] Qavg: nan Conversion failed!

Alguien me puede ayudar? Estoy atascada. Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Descubrí que era...me faltaba indicar la extensión del archivo .txt "enc.keyinfo"  en el código.